# Using attr_reader with a private method of the same instance var name

Tags: ruby

I just encountered a use case where we have a class with an instance variable `@errors` that is memorized via private method of the same name.

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :errors

  private

  # memoized method
  def errors
    @errors ||= []
  end
end

f = Foo.new

# private method `errors' called for #<Foo:...
f.errors
```

What is the solution here? Use `#instance_variable_get` or rename the attribute or method?

Comment: Personally, I would just rename the private method to `init_errors` or something like that as it seems like the simplest thing to do. Is there a reason you don't want to rename the private method? 

Also, say if we were to have both `attr_reader :errors` and the private method called `errors`, then inside the class `Foo` `errors` is ambiguous, it could refer to both the private method or the non private method `errors` as `attr_reader` just defines method `errors` on the class as I understand it.

Comment: No, there will be no ambiguity. Later method definitions simply overwrite earlier ones. The `attr_reader` line in the OP's code is completely superfluous, the method is overwritten 5 lines later anyway.

Comment: Just drop the `attr_reader` and move the memoizing method to public.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the intent expressed by your initial code is best satisfied by: not-using the attr_reader but instead exposing the memoized method at the public level of encapsulation.

(By the way, instead the protected memoized method eclipses the definition of the attr_reader, so the intent of the code -- public non-memoized access but private memoized access -- isn't actually satisfied.)

Consider two alternatives regarding the intent:

1. Public access always occurs after some private access of the :errors reader.
2. Public access does not always occur after some private access of the :errors reader.

In case 1, there is no logical change by exposing the memoized method and discarding the attr_reader; the intent is still achieved.
In case 2, the only logical change relative to the intent, caused by exposing the memoized method and removing the attr_reader, is that public access prior to private access now will memoize and return an empty array rather than returning nil.

If you're expecting case 2, it's very unlikely you're depending on the non-memoization during public access prior to private access, so instead you may be relying on a nil response.  This is a code smell (per *Clean Code* by Robert Martin): it's best, if possible, never to pass nor return nil.

Instead, if case 2 is an issue, the best subsequent change is to make that code that depends on nil being returned for public access prior to private access INSTEAD depend on an empty array being returned for public access prior to private access, in the same way that public access *after* private access would. If this is not possible or undesirable, please clarify further.

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want to keep the reader method private, you may use `method_missing` to redirect the calls to `errors` inside your class. For example:

```rb
class Foo
  attr_reader :errors

  # Add method_missing here
  def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
    if method_name.to_s == 'errors'
      errors
    else
      super
    end
  end

  private

  # memoized method
  def errors
    @errors ||= []
  end
end

f = Foo.new

puts f.errors.to_s # => []
```

However, as @SergioTulentsev posted in comments, this could add complexity to your code, especially when the class is already very big.

Comment: While this makes the original "broken" code work, it does so by adding even more complexity and confusion. It's a wrong way to solve this. The proper way would be to get rid of that weird convention of "we have an attr_reader and also a regular reader, which don't interact the way we imagined"

Comment: Agreed: method_missing, as metaprogramming, has an extremely high cognitive load, and so should be reserved for solutions that deliver enormous value and quickly become established conventions that legitimize the use of such heavy artillery.  That is not the case here, so avoid method_missing.